# Subclass cannot be applied to Super class Java

Tags: java, generics, casting, abstract-class, subclass

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyObject<T extends DescriptionItem> {

    protected abstract MyObject generate(T item);
}
```

which has the following subclass:

```
public class AudioObject extends MyObject<PlayNowDescriptionItem> {

    @Override
    protected MyObject generate(PlayNowDescriptionItem item) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

PlayNowDescriptionItem extends DescriptionItem. I also have a factory class for generating objects.

```
public class ObjectFactory {

 public MyObject generateCastObject(DescriptionItem item) {
    if (item instanceof PlayNowDescriptionItem) {
        return new AudioObject(context).generate(item);
}
```

I thought that this would work fine because PlayNowDescriptionItem is a child of DescriptionItem, but i get an error on the following line.

```
     return new AudioObject(context).generate(item);
```

PlayNowDecriptionItem in AudioObject cannot be applied to DescriptionItem.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to cast explicitly: `.generate((PlayNowDescriptionItem) item);`.

Comment: Hei why is the answer no longer marked as accepted ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast your `DescriptionItem` to `PlayNowDescriptionItem` like this:

```
return new AudioObject(context).generate((PlayNowDescriptionItem)item);
```

as you defined the generate method to accept a subclass of DescriptionItem (please note that an object of class `PlayNowDescriptionItem` is also an object of class `DescriptionItem` but the contrary is not always valid, eg. could be a subclass `PlayAfterDescriptionItem` that's is not a `PlayNowDescriptionItem`)